# finding neighbor patches of specific turtle in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

how to find neighbors patches of the desired turtle and not turtle's own neighbors. so to find out empty neighbors of the specific turtle as seed or stationary turtle and ask other turtles to go there and stop.

I am using neighbors with command but it always sees its own neighbors. Also want to use `(fd 1)` and not `(move-to)` command

like this.

```
ask turtles with [stationary? != true and seed? = false]  [
    let empty-patches neighbors with [not any? robots-here with [stationary? = true]]
    ifelse any? empty-patches
      [ let target one-of empty-patches
        face target
        fd 0.1
      ]
      [
        set stationary? true
        set localized? true
        stop
        ]
 ]

end
```

Comment: It sounds like you are hoping to use `([neighbors] of target-turtle)` where you use `neighbors`.  (Of course you will have to define `target-turtle`.)

Comment: Thanx Alan, yes I also tried like that you mentioned.

Comment: here what I am trying to do:                                                                     `let empty [neighbors with [not any? robots-here] ] of robots  with [stationary? = true]
        if any? empty
     [
          let target one-of emp
          face one-of target
          move-to one-of  target 
          set stationary? true
      ]`  but this didn't give me the solution, as it gave me error for `move-to` that "MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead. " after running for some turtles(robots) correcdtly placing them near stationary robots

Comment: Instead try `let empty (patch-set [neighbors with [not any? robots-here] ] of robots with [stationary? = true]) if any? empty [ let target one-of empty move-to target set stationary? true ]`

Comment: yes, it worked. Alan, Thanx for your kindness. As a next step, which I actually want that to do the same by using `fd 1` instead of `move-to` statement for gradually moving towards the target and become stationary on `(patch-set [neighbors with [not any? robots-here] ] of robots with [stationary? = true])`

Comment: @YasirDarr: To ask a new question, please open a new question.

Comment: ok thanks, Seth tissue